# Best way to roll log file in GO

Tags: logging, go

Is anyone who is using go language in production faced problem with rolling of log files?

Is there any possibility to roll log file thread safely?

Are there any frameworks that make this?

Thank you.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal I'm interesting of real user experience. I guess people faced same problems with thousands of logs files. Can you recommend exact implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an internal solution. You can consider having a single goroutine responsible for logging and log rotation with a channel where it receives logs from other goroutines. Whenever it is time to rotate, the goroutine will rotate the log, while the incoming logs from other goroutines are enqueued on the channel. After log rotation is completed, it will then dequeue whatever is on the channel and continue logging.

Something along the lines of:

```
type Log struct {

    log string
    // other info you might want
}

// This will be your goroutine
func Logging(LogChannel chan Log) {

    // assume logger creates/opens a file and prepares it for writing  
    logger := New(logger) 

    for {

        // collect a log. Will also block until a log is available on the channel
        log <- LogChannel

        if timeToRotate() {

            RotateLogFile(logger)

        }

        // write log 
        logger.Log(log)
    }
}
```

EDIT: The previous code had the blocking call after checking if the log file rotated. It is better to put it before the `timeToRotate` function call to prevent the possibility of writing the log after the log file has rotated

Comment: That looks like perfect solution!

Answer (score 7):

i've had good success with https://github.com/natefinch/lumberjack it's lightweight and piggy backs on golang's standard and memory efficient "log" pkg.

very simple to use, just add one line of code to set it up, and use log as normal:

```
log.SetOutput(&lumberjack.Logger{
    Filename:   "/var/log/myapp/foo.log",
    MaxSize:    500, // megabytes
    MaxBackups: 3,
    MaxAge:     28, //days
})
```

Comment: I've used this too for small one off projects.  But for any large scale deployment, avoid logging to disk and go to stdout/stderr and let the infrastructure deal with mass logging.

Answer (score 5):

I tend to take the [12 Factor](http://12factor.net/) approach of logging to std error and letting something else deal with the rotation.

Then, you have the system rotate the logs for you, as is mentioned [here](https://paperairoplane.net/?p=725)

Comment: Absolutely agree.  When you have 15+ projects running, with dozens (or 100s) of instances of each, you want all of its output to stdout/stderr for logging.  This allows the devops team (or yourself) to offload the logging however needed. For example, stream it to AWS' CloudWatch Logs service where you can filter and group and setup alerts.

Answer (score 2):

What I usually do is not use log files directly. Either you write to a network logger, like scribe or kafka, etc; Or preferably, you write to stdout/stderr, and have the service runner deal with writing to logfiles, forwarding to a network logger, or rotating the files.

Comment: What service runner do you recommend for that?